# How can I access each record in spring batch listener when exception is thrown?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-batch

Hi I am working on spring batch project.

This project uses JdbcCursorItemReader and some times it throws a couple of sql exceptions.
For now, I do not really care if this happens. However, I would like to know what exception was thrown and what item had a problem causing the exception.

I saw some people suggesting to use Listener in other posts.

I have implemented the following code

```
@Component
class SomeReaderListener implements ItemReadListener<SomeEntity> {
  @Override
  void before(){}

  @Override
  void afterRead(SomeEntity item) {
    log.info("SomeEntity: ${item}");
  }

  @Override
  void onReadError(Exception ex) {
    log.info("SomeEntity: ${ex.getClass()}|${ex.getMessage()}");
  }
}
```

In the log, it logs all the items as expected.
However, what I want is only the logs of item if there was an exception thrown.
But how do I have access to the `item` in `onReadError`

I thought of the following approach.

1. create arrayList as bean
2. add all the item into the arrayList in the `afterRead`
3. remove those item from the arrayList, unless exception is thrown `onReadError`. If there is an exception, then prints the item in the `onReadError` function as well.

*** Edit:
I just thought it does not have be the arrayList at all. Just create a bean of object and replace it in each step with arrayList. But I do not think I have ever seen such code. I still think it is very bad code.

However, this approach seems extremely inefficient. The exception is not thrown very often and I have a couple thousand records. It does not make sense to add each record in the arrayList and remove it right after...
Also, I believe spring batch offers a way better way to do what I am trying.
Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Sorry it is not possible. Which "item" can you expect (except null), when "read (of that item) fails"?? (Who should lay the egg, when the hen died?) ... the best you could get: is some (relevant) information from exception (object), or the listener *has* this information (but not through interface methods).

Comment: Thank you so much for you comment!!! :) I see. maybe print all the "item" in the `afterRead` might be the way to go for now. And if the exception is thrown, I will print the class name and message to see what was the cause.

Comment: Welcome! And to be "less verbose"/to save useless logging, you could also do nothing on/not implement `afterRead(T)` (but just focus on`ReadError`!?;) ..and though you cannot get the (successfully) "read item", you can have all the information, the reader had at that "line/row".. (when exception occurred)